# AngularJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting the below error when trying to use html5Mode with ui-router. Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Gb (angular.min.js?F5CH=J:93)
    at Me.$get (angular.min.js?F5CH=J:100)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.min.js?F5CH=J:36)
    at angular.min.js?F5CH=J:38
    at d (angular.min.js?F5CH=J:36)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.min.js?F5CH=J:36)
    at angular.min.js?F5CH=J:38
    at d (angular.min.js?F5CH=J:36)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.min.js?F5CH=J:36)
    at angular.min.js?F5CH=J:47
```

Comment: `undefined` doesn't have any properties or methods.

Comment: I'm getting the above error when trying to use html5Mode with ui-router. Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: could you add some angular code?

Comment: give more code to test and its simple that you are using replace on an undefined variable. Check why it is undefined.